# How to return C# two dimensional array to VBScript

Tags: c#, excel, vba

I am planning to develop a function in C# which will return a two dimensional array. This new C# function will be called through VB script. Also the length of the returned array will be dynamically changed so I am not sure how to return this array to vbscript.

Any insight on approach/pseudo code will be of great help. Thanks.

Comment: VB or VBA?  Make up your mind...

Comment: Do you want to import your data into excel? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/default.aspx

Comment: Actually it's VBA. Yes I would like to access data in the VBA code for performing some further operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend looking at a specialised solution for C# and VBA like [ManagedXLL](http://www.managedxll.com/en/?page=intro),  [ExcelDNA](http://exceldna.typepad.com/blog/) etc if you are going to be doing more of this in the future.

This will help you easily create an in-process XLL that can be called from Excel / VBA directly.

Otherwise you could also call a web service instead as the [2003 Web Services Toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=fa36018a-e1cf-48a3-9b35-169d819ecf18&displaylang=en)  is very easy to set up too.

Comment: I tried assigning array to a variant variable and it works fine. The only problem is we can not see the array values by providing an index to the variable.